# "Git for windows" em português

Tags: git

Após a instalação do git para Windows, é possível configurá-lo para o idioma português?

Apenas definir as variáveis de língua como "LANG=pt_BR" (ou outras) não funciona. Tem que instalar um pacote adicional do idioma? Como?

Answer (score 0):

Olhei aqui no site deles e a tradução para o portugues acabou de ser iniciada, então creio que ainda não seja disponível usar traduzido, vc pode ver as traduções completas, em andamento e as iniciadas no menu lateral aqui https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v2

EDIT
Acho que ainda não é possivel, mas vc pode tentar com `alias git='LANG=pt_BR.UTF-8 git'`

ou
`alias git='LC_ALL=pt_BR.UTF-8 git'`

Voce pode ver suas variaveis de linguagem dando um `locale`, caso a variavel `LC_ALL` não estiver definida, vc pode tentar definir ela também, dando um `export LC_ALL='pt_BR.UTF-8`

Comment: A tradução que citada (link) é do livro (Pro Git 2rd Edition) e não do Git.

Comment: Pelo oq eu andei pesquisando e tentando, acho que não é possivel, dá uma olhada no edit da minha resposta e tenta alguma dessas alternativas como último caso

Comment: Sem chances, não há o pacote de língua instalado na respectiva pasta. Foi a primeira coisa que fizemos antes de pesquisar e vir até aqui procurar por ajuda.